# Angular6 implement both ControlValueAccessor and standard input/output

Tags: angular

can I implement both - ControlValueAccessor and standard @Input and @Output - on custom component?

I have a custom select-box with typeahead functionality, I use it either in form and also standalone without a form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. Those are 2 separate interfaces which you can use in parallel.

You could even use `@Input` property and then call function you've registered with `registerOnChange` so it would be propagated to the parent form.

Also, works the other way around. In your `writeValue(val)` function ()part of `ControlValueAccessor` interface, you could raise custom event used in `@Output` to notitify parent about change.

long story short: yes.